# minikube tunnel command show an error when add a route

Tags: kubernetes, minikube

I've installed minikube over VirtualBox in a Windows 10 Home

I am trying to run command: `minikube tunnel` but I get an error:

```
Status:
        machine: minikube
        pid: 10896
        route: 10.96.0.0/12 -> 192.168.99.101
        minikube: Running
        services: []
    errors:
                minikube: no errors
                router: error adding route: Error en la adici�n de la ruta: El objeto ya existe.

, 3
                loadbalancer emulator: no errors
```

It is the error message (translated):

```
Error in route addition: Object exists already.
```

I would like to know why I get an error in router section?

Thanks in advance

Comment: is that happens after clean minikube install? or you already tried to delete minukube, install again, etc

Comment: @VKR I use an old installation. I try again uninstalling and make a new installation. I get the same error

Comment: It seem to me that you have to run your PowerShell or CMD as administrator. https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/7644#issuecomment-616049169

Comment: still doesn't work with admin either

Answer (score 1):

Solution to this : This solution works to me

Run minikube tunnel in powershell . Run PowerShell as administrator

```
PS C:\Users\QL752LU> minikube tunnel
Status:
        machine: minikube
        pid: 9272
        route: 10.96.0.0/12 -> 192.168.59.100
        minikube: Running
        services: [dockerml]
    errors:
                minikube: no errors
                router: no errors
                loadbalancer emulator: no errors
Status:
        machine: minikube
        pid: 9272
        route: 10.96.0.0/12 -> 192.168.59.100
        minikube: Running
        services: [dockerml]
    errors:
                minikube: no errors
                router: no errors
                loadbalancer emulator: no errors
Status:
```

Answer (score 0):

Run command prompt as administrator, it also works

C:\Windows\system32>minikube tunnel
Status:
machine: minikube
pid: 64536
route: 10.96.0.0/12 -> 192.168.59.100
minikube: Running
services: [balanced]
errors:
minikube: no errors
router: no errors
loadbalancer emulator: no errors